# Getting an error in Bitz and pizza app that i am using to build it with Head first android development book

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-pageradapter, android-developer-api

When i am adding viewpager using fragment pager adapter....it show error ,all the code looks fine but in mainactivity.java its an error.

I think mainly the problem is in the import function, which is used in older version ....but i can't find anything in any of the browsers(google and youtube etc.

My code of main activity is this:-

```
 package com.hfad.bitzandpizza;

 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

 import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

 import android.content.Intent;

 import android.os.Bundle;

 import android.view.Menu;

 import android.view.MenuItem;

 import androidx.appcompat.widget.ShareActionProvider;

  import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

  import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat;

 import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

 import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

 import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    SectionspagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}

    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) 
    MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
    setShareActionIntent("Want to join me for pizza?");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }


   private void setShareActionIntent(String text){
    Intent intent = new Intent((Intent.ACTION_SEND));
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT ,text);
    shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
  }

  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_create_order:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this , OrderActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
 }


    private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
public int getCount(){
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position){
        switch (position){
            case 0 :
                return  new TopFragment();
            case 1:
                return new PizzaFragment();
            case 2:
                return new PastaFragment();
            case 3:
                return new StoresFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }
  }

 }
```

please check this....to find an error it ruins my 2 days .....

Thankyou very much

[first error is descripted pager adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp1CA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lwZS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ56i.png)

these are all the error I have encountered......

Comment: Could you share us the screenshot which import became red? Maybe the dependencies wasn't included in your project?

Comment: @mochadwi i have add the screen shot of my error in post.....please see them and please tell what should i do to remove this........thank you for your contribution

Comment: Looks like the `SectionsPagerAdapter` is in a `private` scope, therefore you cannot access it (it'll red in other classes, if it not in the same package/class)

Comment: For the `FragmentPagerAdapter` parts, as stated in the official docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter

**Switch to ViewPager2 and use FragmentStateAdapter instead.** but this might confusing at the moment, so I suggest, you leave it as-is for `FragmentPagerAdapter` class and still using it

Comment: @mochadwi but sir, how can i remove the error....can u explain me in brief............because i am newbie to android development i can't understand if I leave it how can i proceed without removing error.......Thank you very much

Comment: how about changing this line: `private class SectionsPagerAdapter` to `public class SectionsPagerAdapter`?

Comment: it do nothing.......the error is still same....

and what about FragmentpagerAdapter.......the last three case in switch statement is still showing error..

Comment: @mochadwi If  u have time, can u please examine my full code and explain me the mistakes i have done.....in google meet because nothing had happen when I use public instead of private.......Thank you......if u agree please reply, i will provide the link in the comment........it takes only 10 min. and by this u can save my upcoming days in learning more concepts in android development.....at this time it takes my 3 days to find error....thankyou for ur support and help.

Comment: did you familiar with gitlab or github? maybe you can hosting your code there, and we'll try to inspect your code

Comment: @mochadwi No sir, but if you gives me the steps that i will follow.......i am very thankful to you

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/create-a-repo you can create a repo first